# Do multiple flash movies on a web page download and run in parallel or in sequence

Tags: javascript, flash, flash-cs3

We have a flash website built using flex and CS3. Majority of the site has been done using flex. We have multiple flash movies on a page and we obviously have the page loading very slow. Now that we are looking into options for making the page fast, we are trying to understand whether we can run these flash movies in parallel ? Is there some provision in CS3 to make the flash understand that this object will be loaded and ran first and then the second object.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try bulk-loader library. 
http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the swfs are run as they are loaded, but I think you can have something to say about that.

As far as I understand you have multiple swfs displayed in one HTML file.

If that is the case, you can use [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) to establish communication between swfs and control the way each and every one initializes.

Another option would be setting a variable (be it js variable, js cookie, local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/SharedObject.html), etc. ) to keep track of the currently loaded swf's ID (e.g. 1 of 13 ). Working with js and flash is done using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

If I didn't understand, and you only want to load multiple swfs into one swf and manage that, [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) is the way forward as mentioned before.

Goodluck!